# Does the Architect know martial arts?

Tags: the-matrix

I would like to know if the Architect knows martial arts. If the agents in the Matrix know martial arts, then this makes me think that the Architect must know martial arts and that he would be capable of defending himself in hand-to-hand combat.

[image]

Does the Architect know martial arts?

Neo gained his martial arts skills by having these skills downloaded to his brain. I would think then that downloadable martial arts skills are also available to the Architect and he can quickly download these skills, enabling him to defend himself in hand-to-hand combat if there ever is a sudden need for it.

Comment: "If the agents in the Matrix know martial arts, then this makes me believe that the Architect must know martial arts"  Why?  Do you think the programmers that wrote the code for Street Fighter or Mortal Kombat all know martial arts?

Comment: @Kevin, no, those programmers would not know martial arts just by typing code on their keyboards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Almost certainly no

I'm not aware of any depiction of the Architect using martial arts, and [his article on the Matrix wiki](https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/The_Architect) doesn't mention anything, either.

Logically, he wouldn't need to know martial arts since it's almost impossible for anyone to reach him (you have to be The One and obtain a special key from a special Keymaker program).

Finally, each machine has a rigidly defined purpose and risks deletion for straying outside that purpose. The Architect's purpose does not require him to know martial arts so it's very unlikely he would know how to defend himself "physically".

Answer (score 3):

A answer attempt assuming there is no concrete answer:

Every human job and every program has a primary purpose. Adding stuff not needed for that purpose can cause all sorts of incompatibility and conflicts down the line.

Giving the Architect martial arts skills, could have actively made him a worse Architect of a believeable virtual reality. And he *already* was not performing optimally to begin with - he needed help from the Oracle to even get the bodge job we see in the movie working!

Exiled Programs were a lot more liberal in what they learned. They had already outlived their intended purpose. If you are no longer used as cat behavioral controller, combat skills can not make you worse at your job. And those skills drastically increase your chances against agents if you are detected.